# Add/remove xml tags using a bash script

Tags: xml, bash, scripting

I have an xml file that I want to configure using a bash script.  For example if I had this xml:

```
<a>

  <b>
    <bb>
        <yyy>
            Bla 
        </yyy>
    </bb>
  </b>

  <c>
    <cc>
      Something
    </cc>
  </c>

  <d>
    bla
  </d>
</a>
```

*(confidential info removed)*

I would like to write a bash script that will remove section `<b>` (or comment it) but keep the rest of the xml intact.  I am pretty new the the whole scripting thing.  I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint as to what I should look into.

I was thinking that sed could be used *except* sed is a line editor.  I think it would be easy to remove the `<b>` tags however I am unsure if sed would be able to remove all the text **between** the `<b>` tags.

I will also need to write a script to add back the deleted section.

Comment: I would have to advise against using bash/sed/awk/etc. for this sort of thing and recommend using Python, Ruby or Perl.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This would not be difficult to do in sed, as sed also works on ranges.

Try this (assuming xml is in a file named foo.xml):

```
sed -i '/<b>/,/<\/b>/d' foo.xml
```

-i will write the change into the original file (use -i.bak to keep a backup copy of the original)

This sed command will perform an action d (delete) on all of the lines specified by the range

```
# all of the lines between a line that matches <b>
# and the next line that matches <\/b>, inclusive
/<b>/,/<\/b>/
```

So, in plain English, this command will delete all of the lines between and including the line with <b> and the line with </b>

If you'd rather comment out the lines, try one of these:

```
# block comment
sed -i 's/<b>/<!-- <b>/; s/<\/b>/<\/b> -->/' foo.xml

# comment out every line in the range
sed -i '/<b>/,/<\/b>/s/.*/<!-- & -->/' foo.xml
```

Comment: This works if there's nothing of importance on preceding `<b>` on the same line, and nothing of importance following `</b>` on the same line, i.e. doesn't work for XML in general but may work for the asker's special case.

Comment: The block comment (replacing <b> with <!-- <b> and </b> with </b> -->) would work if there was anything important on the line before <b> or after </b>.

The biggest problem with that would be if there was already a comment inside of the commented block -- xml doesn't like nested comments.

Comment: Plenty of other cases this doesn't handle -- for instance, it can't distinguish tags from literal text inside a CDATA block. Much, much better to use XML-aware tools for the job.

Comment: Thanks :) it works well for multi line tags, but doesn't work at all for a tag on an unique line, such as <b>my text here</b>

Answer (score 16):

Using xmlstarlet:

```
#xmlstarlet ed -d "/a/b" file.xml > tmp.xml
xmlstarlet ed -d "//b" file.xml > tmp.xml
mv tmp.xml file.xml
```

Comment: Should probably do it right and add a conditional (to only rename over the original file if the operation succeeds). To do it even more right, one might also use `mktemp` to generate a temporary file with a guaranteed-nonconflicting name, which can also have the side effect of avoiding some security attacks related to use of constant temporary file names.

Comment: Even with those caveats, though, this is still a much better answer than using `sed`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an XSLT such as this that is a modified identity transform.  It copies all of the content by default, and has an empty template for `b` that does nothing(effectively deleting from output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<!--Identity transform copies all items by default -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Empty template to match on b elements and prevent it from being copied to output -->
<xsl:template match="b"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Create a bash script that executes the transform [using Java and the Xalan commandline utility](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html) like this:

> java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN
>   foo.xml -XSL foo.xsl -OUT foo.out

The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><a><c><cc>
      Something
    </cc></c><d>
    bla
  </d></a>
```

---

**EDIT:** if you would prefer to have the `b` commented out, to make it easier to put back, then use this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <!--Identity transform copies all items by default -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Match on b element, wrap in a comment and construct text representing XML structure by applying templates in "comment" mode -->
    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="comment" />
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="comment">
        <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="comment" />
        <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/'"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="comment">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="comment">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><a><!--<b><bb><yyy>
            Bla
        </yyy></bb></b>--><c><cc>
      Something
    </cc></c><d>
    bla
  </d></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the most appropriate replacement for `sed` for XML data, it would be an XSLT processor.  Like `sed` it's a complex language but specialized for the task of XML-to-anything transformations.

On the other hand, this *does* seem to be the point at which I would seriously consider switching to a real programming language, like Python.

Comment: That consideration adds to my perception of XML being overkill for configuration files ;)

Answer (score 3):

@OP, you can use awk eg

```
$ cat file
<a>                              

some text before   <b>
    <bb>
        <yyy>
            Bla
        </yyy>
    </bb>
  </b> some text after

  <c>
    <cc>
      Something
    </cc>
  </c>

  <d>
    bla
  </d>
</a>

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="</b>"}/<b>/{gsub(/<b>.*/,"")}1' file
<a>

some text before
 some text after

  <c>
    <cc>
      Something
    </cc>
  </c>

  <d>
    bla
  </d>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# edit file inplace
xmlstarlet ed -L -d "//b" file.xml
```

Comment: apt-get install xmlstarlet
on ubuntu 9.x version, with default repositories.
did not find -L flag in documentation.

is it in ubuntu 10.0.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/<b>/,/<\/b>/d' foo.xml
```

Will this work if b tag has a value defined as well
in about HTML, b tag starts as `<b id="Test Step">`

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?