# Add/remove xml field from svg file with bash

Tags: xml, bash, svg, sed

I have a set of svg images that I would like to modify with a bash script. In particular, I would like to remove specific paths from the image by preserving the others. This is a working example:

```
<path
  id="rect5505"
  d="M 118.34375,20 C ... z"
  style="fill:#4d8ecb;stroke:none;fill-opacity:1" />
<path
  style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.23529412;stroke:none;display:inline"
  d="m ... z"
  id="path17954"
  sodipodi:nodetypes="ssccccccccccccssccccccs" />
```

In this case, there are two `path` elements, but I would like to remove only the one that has `fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0.23529412`. I know that I can use `sed` in order to identify the line that has these fields, but how can I remove the whole `path` field?

I would like to underline that this issue is not a duplicate of [Add/remove xml tags using a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561946/add-remove-xml-tags-using-a-bash-script), since in that case there was a single field type. By using something like

```
sed -i '/<path/,/<\/>/d' image.svg
```

I would remove every single path in the file, isn't it?

Comment: Use an xml parser like xmllint

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027314/59087

Comment: @DaveJarvis, how is a Java question relevant here? (Particularly since this is possible -- even easy -- to do robustly with command-line accessible tools, as in the answer by Wintermute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing XML with sed is not a terribly good idea. My suggestion is to use `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//path[contains(@style, "fill:#000000") and contains(@style, "fill-opacity:0.23529412")]' filename.xml
```

Where

```
xmlstarlet ed -d xpath filename.xml
```

deletes from `filename.xml` those elements that match the given XPath expression, and

```
//path[contains(@style, "fill:#000000") and contains(@style, "fill-opacity:0.23529412")]
```

is an XPath expression that matches all `path` nodes that have a `style` attribute that contains both `fill:#000000` and `fill-opacity:0.23529412`.

**Addendum:** Since `contains()` does simple string comparison, the XPath expression used above may, in some corner cases, yield false positives. For example, if the `style` attribute contains the string `foo-fill:#000000` , `contains(@style, "fill:#000000")` will be true. A simple if somewhat unwieldy way around this particular problem is to use

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//path[contains(concat(";", @style, ";"), ";fill:#000000;") and contains(concat(";", @style, ";"), ";fill-opacity:0.23529412;")]' filename.xml
```

...although this still leaves the issue of whitespaces. I suppose a perfect solution would have to parse the CSS as well as the XML, which would take more doing (and probably Perl or so).

**Addendum 2:** It appears we have [namespace SNAFU](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html). To fix that, use

```
xmlstarlet ed -N svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' -d '//svg:path[contains(@style, "fill:#000000") and contains(@style, "fill-opacity:0.23529412")]' accessibility.svg
```

That is:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' -d xpath filename
```

with `xpath` amended to use `svg:path` instead of `path`. This is necessary because there is an attribute

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

in the `svg` tag of the input file, and XPath requires that to be handled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Wintermute. I am trying to use it on this image (one of the many): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alecive/FlatWoken/master/FlatWoken/scalable/apps/accessibility.svg . The path I would like to remove is there, but the script gives me an error: `None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
use '_' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual).
For instance, use /_:node instead of /node`